# Spark structured streaming - use of batchId in foreachBatch

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

The [spark structured streaming docs, section foreachbatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch) says

> By default, foreachBatch provides only **at-least-once write guarantees**.
> However, you can use the **batchId** provided to the function as way to
> deduplicate the output and get an **exactly-once guarantee**.

Let's have a dummy example. Say I am working with a dummy streamed df with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

I have setup a writeStream as follows:

```
writing_sink = df.writeStream\
  .outputMode("append") \
  .foreachBatch(write_to_db_using_jdbc)\
  .start()
```

My fn executed on every micro-batch:

```
def write_to_db_using_jdbc(df, epoch_id):
    # posts the df (start, end, count) to a SQL db using JDBC
```

What would be the use of **batchId** in order to achieve **exactly-once guarantee**?

Comment: you must check your target store/process for the existence of that id.  If you find it you can stop trying to store it again.  There is no automatic solution here, you have to use the id to provide the guarantee

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on how spark assigns ids to batches? When working with aggregated data, I assume a certain aggregation will always end up with the same id.

Comment: The exact mechanism is dependent on the source.  You should think of them as a certain "chunk" of rows in the batch is identical, it doesn't really matter how they get there (aggregation or rows filter or timeliness etc..)